# Setting application recycling settings for COM+ component from code / command line

Tags: c#, vbscript, com+

I have following question:
How can I from c# code or command line script configure Application Recycling settings ?
( please see screenshot below ) 
I did not succeeded to find appropriate .NET attributes
Your help will be very valuable
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. YEs , I need that COM+component will be registered with the settings during installation . If it can be done from bat it will be OK .

Comment: Thanks for link . I tried sample code from the MSDN article, but after run , the settings were not changed . Do I need to perform more operations ( save , commit etc ) ? Thanks

Comment: I modified it for VBScript , and it already works . Thanks

Comment: Really - after running modified VBScript , you need only to refresh DCOMCNFG UI ..

Answer (score 1):

Setting Application Recycling properties of COM+ application is certainly not possible with `.bat` script per se. To my knowledge, there is no .NET attribute or `System.EnterpriseServices` helper for doing that either.

`COMAdmin` is a way to set COM+ application's properties programmatically. See [Configuring COM+ Application Recycling Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684192.aspx) MSDN page. The page features sample VB6 code for configuring Application Recycling properties.

Below is straightforward port of MSDN sample to VBScript.

```vb
If Not SetMyApplicationRecycling("MyApp", 5, 10, 9, 100, 20) Then
    MsgBox "SetMyApplicationRecycling failed."
End If

Function SetMyApplicationRecycling( _
  strApplicationName, _
  lngLifetimeLimit, _
  lngMemoryLimit, _
  lngCallLimit, _
  lngActivationLimit, _
  lngExpirationTimeout _
)  ' Return False if any errors occur.

    SetMyApplicationRecycling = False  ' Initialize the function.
    On Error Resume Next  ' Initialize error handling.

    Dim objAppCollection
    Dim objApplication
    Set objCatalog = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
    Set objAppCollection = objCatalog.GetCollection("Applications")
    objAppCollection.Populate
    For Each objApplication In objAppCollection
        With objApplication
            If .Name = strApplicationName Then
                .value("RecycleLifetimeLimit") = lngLifetimeLimit
                .value("RecycleMemoryLimit") = lngMemoryLimit
                .value("RecycleCallLimit") = lngCallLimit
                .value("RecycleActivationLimit") = lngActivationLimit
                .value("RecycleExpirationTimeout") = lngExpirationTimeout
                objAppCollection.SaveChanges                

                MsgBox strApplicationName & _
                  " recycling values are now set to the following: " & _
                  vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                  "Lifetime Limit (minutes) = " & lngLifetimeLimit & vbNewLine & _
                  "Memory Limit (KB) = " & lngMemoryLimit & vbNewLine & _
                  "Expiration Timeout (minutes) = " & lngExpirationTimeout & vbNewLine & _
                  "Call Limit = " & lngCallLimit & vbNewLine & _
                  "Activation Limit = " & lngActivationLimit

                SetMyApplicationRecycling = True  ' Successful end to procedure
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next

    Set objApplication = Nothing
    Set objAppCollection = Nothing
    Set objCatalog = Nothing

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error # " & Err.Number & " (Hex: " & Hex(Err.Number) _
        & ")" & vbNewLine & Err.Description 
        Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```